# keep session alive using webclient

Tags: webclient

I'm trying to program an application connecting to a website not spammer but some thing like that .

But there is one problem :

In that website you will login by an html form and I know the target php page and parameters so with c# I login like this :

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-urlencoded";
    wc.UploadString("http://example.com/login/check.php", "username=US&password=PW");
    MessageBox.Show(result);
}
```

after logining in when I want to ( for example ) send a post ( like codes below ) the answer is that you are not loged in !

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-urlencoded";
    wc.UploadString("http://example.com/post/send.php", "title=T&body=B");
    MessageBox.Show(result);
}
```

I think the problem is that the session is closed .
what can I do ?

Comment: How does the server track authenticated users?  If the response to the original login includes a cookie then you'll need to save that cookie in your code and use it in your later requests.

Comment: It uses session ( normally with cookie ) . How can I use cookies in my codes ?

Comment: I'm not sure if the `WebClient` object has the operations you need, you'll likely need to poke around in the documentation.  Essentially you need to be able to make an HTTP request which has a richer response, more than just a string.  That response would contain cookies, headers, etc.  Then you'd need to create richer HTTP requests afterward (again, more than just uploading a string), because you'll need to include cookies and headers in those requests.  Maybe `HttpClient`?  Maybe `WebRequest`?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if you found the answer but try this

```
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    string url = @"http://example.com/login/check.php";
    var postData = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
byte[] bytes = webClient.UploadValues(url,"POST",postData);

string text = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```

use Fiddler to look for the parameters.